# "Genetic" hybridization of string data - anyone know of a library?

Tags: string, genetic-algorithm

I am looking for a library that would (semi)-intelligently hybridize two text strings using a variety of methods.

For example:

```
STRING 1: AACADAC
STRING 2: EADDACE

OUTPUT: AACDACE..etc
```

Anyone know of something like this? I do not need a full blown genetic algorithm library, just something to facilitate the "breeding and mutation" component of it (with string data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Library, No. However Assuming you have strings of the same length (as in your example, chromosomes?), it shouldnt be too hard to write one yourself. After all all you are really wanting is array slicing, and a (random?) number of crossover points, to do crossover. Mutation is easily done as it is just a probability and a character operation.